# flask running in mod_wsgi cannot write to /tmp

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

Apache v2.4.12-2

Mod_wsgi v4.4.8-1

Python v3.4.2

python-flask v0.10.1-5

Arch linux - kernel 3.12.36

I'm using mod_wsgi and flask to host a server. I am able to reproduce this issue with the following simplified code and generic .wsgi script:

MainServer.py:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.before_first_request
def initstuff():
    test_file = '/tmp/test'
    with open(test_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write('test')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def rootdir():
    return 'Hello world'
```

MainServer.wsgi:

```
from MainServer import app as application
```

Expected: a file with the contents 'test' is written in /tmp

Actual outcome: No file is written. No errors reported in log

If I run the same code but instead point to any other directory which my user has permission to write, it creates the file as expected. /tmp is the only directory where I am having this issue.

If I run the above code directly and use flask's built in server (app.run), it can create the file in /tmp as expected without any issues.

I've ensured that the mod_wsgi server is running as the same user as the script with app.run is and that this user is able to write to /tmp.

--edit--

Running httpd directly from the command line does not cause this issue. Starting httpd as a systemd service does

Comment: Have you used `strace` to find out what is happening?

Comment: strace is murder on a raspberry pi. Perhaps I should start testing on my desktop... Ran `strace -ooutput httpd`. This terminated when the server finished starting up and didn't include any references to the file I'm attempting to open. Is there a better way to trace applications in apache?

Comment: Make sure you pass the `-f` flag in order to follow through forks.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not particularly familiar with strace. According to the output, it wrote the file successfully, and it did! So I guess not I have another failure condition. Starting httpd with systemctl causes writing to fail while starting httpd directly does not.

Comment: If the file already existed and was created by another user, the user that Apache runs as will not likely be able to write to it. Thus likely a file ownership issue.

Comment: I've ensured that the user who is running the Apache server is the same user who I log into the shell and modify files as. This user has full permissions for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think is related to this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167835/where-apaches-tmp-located

Apache might be using private-tmp which causes /tmp to be redirected to /var/tmp/systemd-private-*-httpd.service-*/

Comment: This is certainly the resolution. Far too late for my original problem, but better late than never :)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `app` logger level to `DEBUG` (and adding a Handler):

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.before_first_request
def initstuff():
    test_file = '/tmp/test'
    with open(test_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write('test')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def rootdir():
    return 'Hello world'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = RotatingFileHandler('app.log', maxBytes=10000, backupCount=1)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8056, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Then look in `app.log` to see what the problem is.

Comment: I had a log setup, but modified it a bit to make it more similar to what you have. I'm not getting any errors or information of interest other than HTTP GET, etc.

Comment: Have you tried just creating the file without using flask to see if there are any errors:  `python -c 'open("/tmp/test", "w").write("FOO")'`

Comment: That works fine. As does writing from flask without mod_wsgi. For example, if I run the following the file is created correctly: `python3 MainServer.py`. But running it in apache with wsgi is when no files are created despite no errors thrown.

Comment: Yes it has permission and /var/log only contains requests and normal debug info from the service startup.

Comment: You can check /var/log/messages or try `chmod 777 /tmp` and if that works after `chmod` then it has to be a permissions or SELinux issue.